# Android calendar colors different from actual values

Tags: android, colors, calendar, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

I'm fetching a list of calendars from Calendar Provider, it works perfectly fine. Along with calendar name, I'm trying to retrieve calendar colour. It works, however the colours are different (somewhat brighter) than the actual colours displayed in Google Calendar app.[image]

I tried using various methods of converting the returned colour to the hex/rgb value, but regardless of the method the result is the same:

```
int mColorCode = (0xff000000 + Integer.parseInt(colorStr));
String color="#"+Integer.toHexString(mColorCode);
int argb = Integer.parseInt(str);
String B = Integer.toString((mColorCode)&0xFF);
String G = Integer.toString((mColorCode>>8)&0xFF);
String R = Integer.toString((mColorCode>>16)&0xFF);
String A = Integer.toString((mColorCode>>24)&0xFF);
String rgbaString = "rgba("+R+","+G+","+B+","+A+")";
```

As shown on the picture above the difference is as follows:

Actual color: #7885cb Returned color: #9a9cff

Actual color: #7cb242 Returned color: #7bd148

The above colours look quite similar but it gets worse for other colours. I thought that maybe there is some filter being applied, but I wasn't able to find any consistent difference between the colours in order to reverse it.

Comment: check the apk on some other device, I think there the color will be the one you are looking for, as sometime color changes as per the Device screen resolutions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it didn't help. Though I discovered that the Calendar app on older devices displays the same lighter colours that I'm receiving. Apparently the new Calendar app do applies some sort of filtering on the colours.

Comment: I discovered that the colour is indeed being changed for on newer Android releases here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar.git/+/android-5.1.0_r3/src/com/android/calendar/agenda/AgendaAdapter.java#181

I'm applying the same filter on my colours and for some calendars the results are close (though not the same), unfortunately calendars from 'More' categeory in the Calendar app have completely different colours.  Also changing colour of such calendars in the Calednar app doesn't cause my colour to change - looks like they are internally defined in the Calenar app.

Comment: Yes I also think that the colors are internally defined in the calendar class.

Comment: The [colors](https://www.cirrusinsight.com/support/gmail/what-is-the-hex-color-code-legend-for-googles-calendar) on the right are the same as they are in FireFox for Google Calendar. Atleast, for me they are.

Answer (score 3):

The Google calendar app makes a transformation on the colors. It uses a hardcoded map to search for color correspondence. If the color is not found on the map, it applies a manual transformation.

This is a simplified (but functional) version of the code:

```
public final class CalendarUtils {

private static final Map<Integer, Integer> sUpdatedColors;

static {
    Map hashMap = new HashMap();
    sUpdatedColors = hashMap;
    hashMap.put(-509406, -2818048);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-370884, -765666);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-35529, -1086464);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-21178, -1010944);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-339611, -606426);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-267901, -1784767);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-4989844, -4142541);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-8662712, -8604862);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-15292571, -16023485);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-12396910, -16738680);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-7151168, -13388167);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-6299161, -16540699);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-6306073, -12417548);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-11958553, -12627531);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-6644481, -8812853);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-4613377, -5005861);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-5997854, -6395473);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-3312410, -7461718);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-3365204, -5434281);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-618062, -2614432);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-3118236, -1672077);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-5475746, -8825528);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-4013374, -10395295);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-3490369, -5792882);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-2350809, -2818048);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-18312, -765666);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-272549, -606426);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-11421879, -16023485);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-8722497, -13388167);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-12134693, -16540699);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-11238163, -12627531);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-5980676, -8812853);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-2380289, -7461718);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-30596, -1672077);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-1973791, -10395295);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-2883584, -2818048);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-831459, -765666);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-1152256, -1086464);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-1076736, -1010944);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-672219, -606426);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-1914036, -1784767);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-4208334, -4142541);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-8670655, -8604862);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-16089278, -16023485);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-16738937, -16738680);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-16606492, -16540699);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-12483341, -12417548);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-12624727, -12627531);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-8878646, -8812853);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-5071654, -5005861);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-7527511, -7461718);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-5500074, -5434281);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-2680225, -2614432);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-1737870, -1672077);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-8891321, -8825528);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-10263709, -10395295);
}

public static int getDisplayColor(int color) {
    if (sUpdatedColors.containsKey(color)) {
        return (sUpdatedColors.get(color));
    }
    if (sUpdatedColors.containsValue(color)) {
        return color;
    }
    float[] fArr = new float[3];
    Color.colorToHSV(color, fArr);
    if (fArr[2] > 0.79f) {
        fArr[1] = Math.min(fArr[1] * 1.3f, 1.0f);
        fArr[2] = fArr[2] * 0.8f;
    }
    return Color.HSVToColor(Color.alpha(color), fArr);
}

}
```

To obtain the transformed color, you can call the getDisplayColor(color) method using the color returned by the Calendar Provider (as the Calendar Provider returns a string, we need to parse it to an integer before):

```
int eventColor = Integer.parseInt(colorStringFromCalendarProvider);
int transformedColor = CalendarUtils.getDisplayColor(eventColor);
```

Answer (score 1):

*I wanted this to be a comments, but I don't know how I can post an image as a comment.*

Instead of converting, you could add the colors hard coded:

- Tomato: 213, 0, 0
- Tangerine: 244, 81, 30
- Banana: 246, 191, 38
- Basil: 11, 128, 67
- Sage: 251, 182, 121
- Peacock: 3, 155, 129
- Blueberry: 63, 81, 181
- Lavender: 121, 134, 203
- Grape: 142, 36, 170
- Flamingo: 230, 124, 115
- Graphite: 97, 97, 97
- Default Blue: 66, 133, 244

[image: Google Calendar Colors in Android and in the Brower]